# JavaScript Injection to Disable the Alert Function

Tags: javascript, vb.net, code-injection

Salutations,

I am working on a project that requires that I control a JavaScript-heavy website from an application created in Visual Basic.

I have been fairly successful with using webBrowser.navigate("javascript:blahblahblah") to login and change values on the website's controls. This would be fine, however the site uses an alert window after I do the injection to log in. Users will not want to see that. I can change the opacity and visibility for the vb frame, but the javascript alert window cannot be hidden using the properties of the frame and the webBrowser control.

So, I'm looking for a way to override the alert function via JavaScript injection (or some other way if possible). I've tried:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:function alert() {};")
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:window.alert = function() { };")
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:alert = function{};")
```

And the alert window still appears.

Any ideas on how to stop the alert windows from appearing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `webBrowswer.Navigate`try `webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript`. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about the InvokeScript method. Unfortunately, I end up getting my user account locked on the web service trying it this way. hmmm. I'll play around with it for a while. Thanks.

Comment: You may have to `Imports System.Security.Permissions` in your form and add attributes `<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _` to your `Public Class YourFormName`